# Javascript named nested array/object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a website with inputboxes that depend on each other. When an element is selected I want to iterate over the dependencies and check the correct item.

Currently I'm stuck on making an array of dependencies, which holds a collection of dependent ID's.

I learned that in Javascript a nested array is actually an object but I can't seem to get my head around the issue.

In pseudo code the array would look like this

```
var dependancies = [
    walls: ['wa1','wa2','wa3']
]
```

Any idea what the easiest way is to translate this into an easy to use JavaScript array/object?

Comment: I know how to use an array, but this array is pseudo code, How do I correctly write the array in good javascript?

Comment: It's not valid Javascript I think? My compiler is wining about it.

Comment: You have to use `var dependancies = {walls: ['wa1', 'wa2', 'wa3']};`

Comment: This could be an interesting question.  I'm curious to see the end result.  Can you give 1 or 2 examples of the dependencies (Who clicks where, and what happens next?) ?  I'm not exactly sure where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: The problem is solved already, it was just a JS array question. I'm using this for a product ordering page, some products require a complementary product that has to be bought also

Answer (score 5):

That would be

```
var dependancies = {
    walls: ['wa1','wa2','wa3']
}
```

Notice the curly brackets instead of the square brackets. You can access ['wa1','wa2','wa3'] using `dependancies.walls` or `dependancies['walls']`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var dependancies = {
    walls: ['wa1','wa2','wa3']
}
```

I think you missed the curly braces.

To fetch a value, use dependancies.walls[0], dependancies.walls[1],...

Answer (score 1):

```
var dependancies = {
    walls: ['wa1','wa2','wa3']
};
```

Should work. You access elements either by typing

```
dependancies['walls'];
```

or

```
dependancies.walls;
```